# Map theme in QGIS

Tags: qgis, print-composer, maptheme

For producing GIS Layout Maps, I am using "Follow Map Theme". However, I have two maps. I want to link the theme of Map 1 to Map 2. How to do that?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE ! Can you provide more context, details ? Do you mean : when you change the map theme of the first map, you want the map theme of the second map change automatically ?

Comment: You could control both maps via the same map theme, couldn't you?

Comment: Create a new layout item variable for your first map `Map 1` named (for e.g.) `map_theme` and as value, the name of your theme `my_theme`. For your second map, you can add as datadriven `Follow map theme` : `map_get(item_variables('Map 1'), 'map_theme')`.

Comment: may be you mean, that the extent of map 2 follows the the extent of the black rectangle on map 1? follow a map_theme in QGIS means to show the visible layers combination defined as a maptheme.

Comment: Yeah, I want that when I change the map theme of the first map, I want the map theme of the second map change automatically.